# Loading Custom Classes at Runtime

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have the below code snippet which I'm trying to load in custom classes from a a directory called `source` but keep getting errors saying `module 'source' has no attribute 'custom_class_1_src'`.

Folder structure:

```
main.py
source
   +----__init__.py
   +----custom_class_1_src.py
   +----custom_class_2_src.py
```

Each class has the class name the same as the file with the first letter capitalised so the class names would be below, and both files have a `__init__` method in them:

```
 Custom_class_1
 Custom_class_2
```

**main.py**

```
import os, pathlib, importlib

def load_class(source, class_name):
    try:
        importlib.invalidate_caches()
        
        module = importlib.import_module('source', source)
        class_ = getattr(module, "{}".format(class_name))
        instance = class_()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

source_directory = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + "/source/"
sources = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(source_directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_directory, f)) and f.endswith('_src.py')])

for source in sources:
    class_name = source.replace("_src.py", "").capitalize()
    
    load_class(source, class_name)
```

**custom_class_1_src.py**

```
class Custom_class_1:

    def __init__(self):
        print("found one file")
```

Comment: There is no file called `class_name.py` so naturally there is no module called `class_name`.

Comment: You have some descrepencies and it's hard to know if that's part of your problem or if it's just a copy error.  For instance, you have import_module('source', ...) but in your directory structure at the top it's `sources`.  You also are looking for files with _src.py, but those aren't in your directory listing.  Neither describe the error, but they make it hard to follow/predict what's happening.

Comment: @saquintes that was a typo on my part, I've fixed it in the question.

Comment: do you have a `__init__`.py file in /source/?

Comment: And it looks like you are passing in custom_class_1_src.py into `imoprt_module('source', source)`.  I think you'll need to strip the .py off.

Comment: @saquintes yes there is an `__init__.py` files in the `source` directory. Stripping the `.py` doesn't make a difference, same error.

Comment: @saquintes got it working with `module = importlib.import_module('source.' + source.replace(".py", ""))`